# numpy 2d boolean array count consecutive True sizes

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, flood-fill

I'm interested in finding out individual sizes of the 'True' patches in a boolean array. For instance in the boolean matrix:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

The output would be:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 4, 4, 0],
 [0, 4, 0, 0],
 [0, 4, 0, 0]]
```

I'm aware that I can do this recursively, but I'm also under the impression that python array operations are costly on large scale and is there an available library function for this?

Comment: For whatever reason, you'll tend to find these kinds of clustering algorithms in image manipulation/computer vision libraries. [`scipy.ndimage.measurements`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage.measurements) has what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick and simple complete solution:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.measurements as mnts

A = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0]
])

# labeled is a version of A with labeled clusters:
#
# [[1 0 0 0]
#  [0 2 2 0]
#  [0 2 0 0]
#  [0 2 0 0]]
#
# clusters holds the number of different clusters: 2
labeled, clusters = mnts.label(A)

# sizes is an array of cluster sizes: [0, 1, 4]
sizes = mnts.sum(A, labeled, index=range(clusters + 1))

# mnts.sum always outputs a float array, so we'll convert sizes to int
sizes = sizes.astype(int)

# get an array with the same shape as labeled and the 
# appropriate values from sizes by indexing one array 
# with the other. See the `numpy` indexing docs for details
labeledBySize = sizes[labeled]

print(labeledBySize)
```

output:

```
[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 4 4 0]
 [0 4 0 0]
 [0 4 0 0]]
```

The trickiest line above is the "fancy" `numpy` indexing:

```
labeledBySize = sizes[labeled]
```

in which one array is used to index the other. See the [`numpy` indexing docs (section "Index arrays")](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) for details on why this works.

I also wrote a version of the above code as a single compact function [that you can try out yourself online.](https://tio.run/##fZBNT8MwDIbv/RWW0LRGRFULt0m9wJUTOwKHrHW3SI0bJSlQ/nzJRxkFJnKxYr9@7Nd6cqeBbudZKj0YBzQqPYGwQDpbUraReiqolUocsVAo7GhQITkbdMrHLLuCbqTGyYHgFY31MWuxg14csL@b9vIDc2EM22XgX8xiy6HpR@u8HOqIKWIhCqPO@rZzzY4qVPh3t6QW32sj6Ij5mXQNFWOFsG7SmEtyiWTQjYYS8GkBvPD4Dbs7tA7epDuBp7WDAj9ITNAN5q8tX/IrkS6SNAY/Jy/5TQTWeVXyqmQs0ybkt48r5O6ZNnYLG4geA@shLZNuxEP@PlnZL@Z/n/AS9uuQyeB6yBp2uXW5Bhz@ofxYks3zJw) It includes a test case based on a random array.

Comment: Thanks! This is very elegant.

Comment: Update, this doesn't work for very strange reasons. Namely, B[B == label] = size doesn't work like expected. the assignment is all off and random - your original code was used on larger matrix -> A size(10,10) random boolean matrix wouldn't have worked.

Comment: I found out where the problem is! For larger matrix with multiple indexes, B[B==label] can have previously changed indexes equal the new label, which are then mistakenly labeled with size.

Comment: @RockyLi Hah. I should have caught that one myself. I've posted a corrected version of the code that removes the loop completely in favor of a single `numpy` fancy indexing operation. There's also a link to a live version online that includes a test case based on a random array

Comment: That is fancy indeed, but actually quite easy to understand! Thanks for the update.